# Passing integer between activities using shared preferences

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass this `SCORE` integer from one activity to another. I'm having difficulties with shared preferences. In MainActivity I don't receive any warnings or errors but in ScoreActivity I receive an error saying *The Method getInt(String, int) in the type Shared Preferences is not applicable for the arguments (long, int)*. How do I fix this?

**MainActivity**

```
private int SCORE = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("SCORE", SCORE);
    editor.commit();
```

**ScoreActivity**

```
private int SCORE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);


    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(SCORE);
    long SCORE = sharedPref.getInt(SCORE, defaultValue);
```

Comment: Try uninstalling the app from the device and do it again...

Comment: @Lal It won't compile because of the error described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
long SCORE = sharedPref.getInt(SCORE, defaultValue); // in your case SCORE is a int
```

Should be

```
int SCORE = sharedPref.getInt("SCORE", defaultValue); 
//"SCORE" is the key
// return's a int value not long
```

Check the docs

```
public abstract int getInt (String key, int defValue)

Added in API level 1
Retrieve an int value from the preferences.

Parameters
key The name of the preference to retrieve.
defValue    Value to return if this preference does not exist.
Returns
Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not an int.
Throws
ClassCastException
```